# Program code as a string

Tags: c#

This is not really for practical use, but is there any way to execute a string as a program code in C#?

For example :
instead of writing

```
Console.WriteLine("blah blah blah");
```

I would like to write something like

```
string s = "Console.WriteLine(\"blah blah blah\")"
execute(s);
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Dynamic code generation](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1748149/dynamic-code-generation)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be done using [Microsoft.CSharp.CSharpCodeProvider](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.csharp.csharpcodeprovider.aspx).

Check [this](http://forums.asp.net/p/1687557/4460622.aspx/1?Re%20compile%20C%20at%20runtime%20using%20system%20reflection%20emit).

Answer (score 1):

The only way I can think of doing this is by compiling your code at runtime. Here is an article that explains how to do this http://simeonpilgrim.com/blog/2007/12/04/compiling-and-running-code-at-runtime/

Answer (score 1):

I know it's not exactly what you asked for (although you didn't mention a the language of the program in the string), but IronPython is very cool: http://secretgeek.net/host_ironpython.asp, http://blogs.msdn.com/b/abhinaba/archive/2006/02/09/528416.aspx.

Also (as boca already mentioned) runtime compilation worked well, too: [Is it possible to dynamically compile and execute C# code fragments?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/826398/is-it-possible-to-dynamically-compile-and-execute-c-code-fragments)

Answer (score 1):

It is *possible* in C#, but it is intentionally *difficult.*  There's no simple "exec()" function you can use out of the box.

AFAIK this is *by design*.  Exec functions are big gaping security holes, because they expose the full power of the language to users who often should not have that power.  As the programmer, you often intend to use an exec() function to allow a user to enter simple math or string expressions, and suddenly you have a hacker come along and instantiate a System.Net.WebClient and use it to download and execute something much more malicious.  There is no way to limit which assemblies are allowed.

The preferred alternative in .Net languages is something called a [Domain Specific Language (DSL)](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/recipes/YourFirstDSL.aspx).  A DSL is a (relatively) easy way to define your own grammar (and the meaning behind it) for what kinds of things you want to allow the user to do, without the security implications of giving them access to the whole base class library.  It also has the advantage of allowing you to provide specialized operations at a higher level than they might otherwise be available.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using CodeDOM. See [Using the CodeDOM](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y2k85ax6.aspx) at MSDN.